# Iphone: NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Hi Im trying to convert an NSString to NSDate

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastModified];
```

But when I do a

```
NSLog(@" date: %@ ", dateFromString);
```

I get date: (null)

The lastModified string has date in string format as "Tue, 15 Feb 2011 13:30:42 GMT"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your input (`lastModified`) does not match the specified date format.

a properly formed string representation of the time specified by `lastModified` for the date format is:

`"2011-02-15 13:30:42 GMT"`, but you're passing `"Tue, 15 Feb 2011 13:30:42 GMT"`.

Comment: my bad changed the format to [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"]; works fine now